# Can I register click-listener after state transition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I have a component that looks like this:

```
<div ref='carousel' onClick={this.mobileZoomOut()} className='carousel'>
```

The mobileZoomout is suppose to register a special condition that only applies to small screens:

```
  mobileZoomOut () {
    const elem = this.state.zoom.carousel
    if (this.zoomed('carousel') && elem.scale < 1.1) {
      this.setState({zoom: {}})
    }
  }
```

The regular zoom is registered like this:

```
this.flky = new Flickity('.carousel', flickityOptions)
this.flky.on('staticClick', (e) => {
  if (this.zoomed()) {
    this.setState({ zoom: {} })
  } else {
    this.zoomIn('carousel', 0.774, 0)
    this.zoomIn('thumbs', 0.208, 0.774)
  }
})
```

staticClick is a custom event from the image-slider flickity, it is disabled when zooming in on mobile. That is why I need another zoom-out-event on mobile.

When adding `mobileZoomOut` I get this error, I believe the reason is that the click event on the carousel register both events, I don't want the onClick to be registered until after the staticClick -event is done.

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

I have tried replacing onClick with `onMouseDown`/`onMouseUp` it does not help. I think I could do it with a timeout, but I would like to avoid that and I'm not really sure how.

Comment: this error is the binding problem, you have not bonded your function to 'this'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your function as a prop, but rather executing it and passing its returned value.
`foo()` executes the foo-function. You want it executed when the event is triggered though.

**this should do the trick**.
`<div ref='carousel' onClick={this.mobileZoomOut} className='carousel'>`

Answer (score 0):

you should be passing reference to function as a props.

```
<div ref='carousel' onClick={this.mobileZoomOut.bind(this)} className='carousel'>
```